# can fuzzy lookup and fuzzy grouping operations be performed in azure data factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

I am new to data factory. For a while I worked on Azure SQL database. Till now all data transformation operations (which includes **data** **movement, processing, modification of data, fuzzy grouping and fuzzy lookup**) are performed manually on my system through SSIS. Now we want to automate all the packages. For that we want to schedule these packages on Azure. I know that Azure SQL has no support for SSIS and someone suggested data factory. Let me know if data factory can perform all my requirements mentioned above.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

Data Factory is not a traditional ETL tool but a tool to orchestrate, schedule and monitor data pipelines that compose existing storage, movement, and processing services.  When you transform data with ADF the actual transformation is done by another service (Hive/Pig script running on HDInsight, Azure Batch, USQL running on Azure Data Lake Analytics, SQL Server Stored Proc, etc.) and ADF manages and orchestrates the complex scheduling and cloud resources. ADF doesn't have traditional 'out of the box' ETL transforms (like fuzzy lookup).  You can write your own scripts or custom .NET code for your business logic, or run stored procedures.  You can compose all of this into a recurring scheduled data pipeline(s) and monitor all in one place.